# GetPrivateProfileSectionNames ran in impersonation block returns 0 when ini file is remote

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, impersonation

I have code that creates an impersonation block to allow read access to a remote ini file, and write access to a remote directory.  When the "remote" directory to write to is truly a remote computer UNC path, the system writes just fine, however if the "remote" ini file is truly a remote UNC path, GetPrivateProfileSectionNames returns 0.  If, however, the "remote" ini file is really just a local UNC path, this function works as expected.  Is there a way to get this function to work as expected for the case where the ini file is truly on a remote computer?

My impersonation block is done using the following disposable class:

```
[PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
public class Impersonation : IDisposable
{
    private WindowsImpersonationContext _impersonatedUserContext;

    // Declare signatures for Win32 LogonUser and CloseHandle APIs
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool LogonUser(
      string principal,
      string authority,
      string password,
      LogonSessionType logonType,
      LogonProvider logonProvider,
      out IntPtr token);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken,
        int impersonationLevel,
        ref IntPtr hNewToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool RevertToSelf();

    // ReSharper disable UnusedMember.Local
    enum LogonSessionType : uint
    {
        Interactive = 2,
        Network,
        Batch,
        Service,
        NetworkCleartext = 8,
        NewCredentials
    }
    // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
    enum LogonProvider : uint
    {
        Default = 0, // default for platform (use this!)
        WinNT35,     // sends smoke signals to authority
        WinNT40,     // uses NTLM
        WinNT50      // negotiates Kerb or NTLM
    }
    // ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming
    // ReSharper restore UnusedMember.Local

    /// <summary>
    /// Class to allow running a segment of code under a given user login context
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="user">domain\user</param>
    /// <param name="password">user's domain password</param>
    public Impersonation(string user, string password)
    {
        var token = ValidateParametersAndGetFirstLoginToken(user, password);

        var duplicateToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref duplicateToken) == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("DuplicateToken call to reset permissions for this token failed");
            }

            var identityForLoggedOnUser = new WindowsIdentity(duplicateToken);
            _impersonatedUserContext = identityForLoggedOnUser.Impersonate();
            if (_impersonatedUserContext == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("WindowsIdentity.Impersonate() failed");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
                CloseHandle(token);
            if (duplicateToken != IntPtr.Zero)
                CloseHandle(duplicateToken);
        }
    }

    private static IntPtr ValidateParametersAndGetFirstLoginToken(string user, string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))
        {
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("No user passed into impersonation class");
        }
        var userHaves = user.Split('\\');
        if (userHaves.Length != 2)
        {
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("User must be formatted as follows: domain\\user");
        }
        if (!RevertToSelf())
        {
            throw new Exception("RevertToSelf call to remove any prior impersonations failed");
        }

        IntPtr token;

        var result = LogonUser(userHaves[1], userHaves[0],
                               password,
                               LogonSessionType.Interactive,
                               LogonProvider.Default,
                               out token);
        if (!result)
        {
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Logon for user " + user + " failed.");
        }
        return token;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Dispose
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Stop impersonation and revert to the process identity
        if (_impersonatedUserContext != null)
        {
            _impersonatedUserContext.Undo();
            _impersonatedUserContext.Dispose();
            _impersonatedUserContext = null;
        }
    }
}
```

While inside of an impersonation block instance of this class, the remote ini file is access by:

```
int bufLen = GetPrivateProfileSectionNames(buffer, 
                                           buffer.GetUpperBound(0),     
                                           iniFileName);
if (bufLen > 0)
{
     //process results
}
```

How do I get GetPrivateProfileSectionNames to return valid data when dealing with a remote computer?  Are there permissions my user needs on this or the remote computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point in time, I've not been able to find information about impersonation and how it interacts with win32 dlls/apis, however, I do know the following:

1) if the entire process is running under a user with access to the remote folder the ini file lives in, then GetPrivateProfileSectionNames works as desired

2) if GetPrivateProfileSectionNames is called inside an impersonation block, then it does not work as desired

3) if a file stream is opened, and the ini file is copied local, then GetPrivateProfileSectionNames is used on the local ini file, then GetPrivateProfileSectionNames works as desired, and the file stream is allowed access to the remote file.

I speculate, based on results, that the win32 api call GetPrivateProfileSectionNames is not getting passed the impersonation context from c#, and thus is running under the overall process context, which does not have access.  I worked around this by caching the ini file local, and tracking when it was last changed so I know if the ini file needs to be re-cached, or if the local copy is correct.